# How can I move the title to the center

Tags: html, css

I want to move the title to green area. If I carry to the container it puts blue area. If I decrease container height title getting closer to the squares. But I want the boxes in the center and the title little above of them. How can I do it?

```css
#container {
  width: 1200;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>TITLE!!!</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9cNv.png)

Comment: I can't see a green area here. Something missing?

Comment: I uploaded a image. at the bottom.

Comment: So why is the title outside of the div? Sounds like you want an element around the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `display: flex;` that's causing the issue. Here's a working model:

```css
#container {
  width: 1200;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>TITLE!!!</h1>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @innocent for adding the "run code snippet" option!

Answer (score 0):

I added a extra wrapper to wrap all the elements and added a display flex to it. Also, You can make use of a `gap` css property in wrapper class to add extra space between them.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
  //border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>TITLE!!!</h1>
  <div id="container">

    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, the other way to solve this would be to use absolute positioning and adding a top padding to allow space for the div header if extra div is really not required.